Do PreparedStatement-s make roundtrip to DB?
It's really hard to find an answer to this.
For the driver let's say it's JDBC, although I believe most other drivers also have PreparedStatement-s.
If they do, then it should be faster to not use PreparedStatement for one-time (non-batch) SQL statements, because PreparedStatement would take two roundtrips total, while regular Statements -- only one.

There's nothing wrong with your logic. Overall, I would not focus on just "number of round trips" and look at the pros and cons all together: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html For a single query not being repeated and apart from concerns about sql injection, you could send the raw sql and let it be prepared and ran in one request to the DB.

If you're going to run a query only once, yes, a PreparedStatement adds a bit of extra overhead. However, if you're going to run a query only once micro-optimizations like this don't matter because it's only run once. Could you give an example where you think performance might matter?

No! There will be no extra roundtrip.

@Schwern Here's the example: a lot of users come to a website and we need to query user full name. Imagine we don't use RAM caches nor connection pooling. Then for each request we create a new DB connection = x2 roundtrips to DB using prepared statements (PS) compared to plain statements. And if we use connection pooling (must-have for high load), then how do we get a preparedstatement for each connection? (PS is tied to a connection, so connection pool must also store prepared statements somehow).

@topsail Yes I'm well aware of benefits, I've been using PreparedStatements for 20+ years. It doesn't answer my question tho.

@AlexanderPetrov Great news, but other commenters are not sure though, could you point to some doc or source code line where I can read more?

Use some tracing and check round trip count yourself.

What database are you using and are you actually using JDBC? You said "although I believe most other drivers also have PreparedStatement-s" I don't know that this is true. SQL Server, for instance, would cache certains types query plans making them re-usable as compiled objects but would do that on the server without "prepared statements". Without any context, its too general of a question other than to say that it makes sense that creating a prepared statement is presumably done by the database server and so would take an extra round trip (what else could possibly be the answer?)

@DzmitryLazerka 1) Since you need parameters to make the query safe (the username) looking up a user should be a prepared statement, performance is irrelevant. 2) Imagine we don't use RAM caches nor connection pooling I imagine you would work on that, it's much more valuable to performance than micro-optimizing. 3) If we use connection pooling, then how do we get a preparedstatement for each connection? Connection affinity, each request gets the same connection from a pool. 4) Have you profiled your app?
